# Does a desktop-bridge app auto-update through the Microsoft store

Tags: visual-c++, uwp, mfc, auto-update, desktop-bridge

I have a traditional Win32 desktop app written in C++/MFC that I have packaged as a UWP app for the Microsoft store using the desktop-bridge facility in Visual Studio 2019. It is currently published on the store, and users have been downloading it successfully.

I now need to release an update. I have incremented the Version numbers in the Packaging tab of the `Package.appxmanifest` and have a package just-about ready to submit to the Store. I hope (expect?) that current users will get their existing copy of the app automatically updated if they have set that choice in the Store app itself, or if they manually check the Store for updates. However, I am not sure whether that is actually true. Do I need to do anything within my program itself to make that happen?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, desktop bridge apps published in the Store update automatically.